# Better version of MPU6050

Tags: gyroscope

[image]I need really good gyroscope for my quadcopter and now I have MPU6050. I don't like how it works, after some time of use, data is absolutely wrong. So I need good gyroscope, could you pls advice the best gyroscope for Arduino?

Comment: "after some time of use, data is absolutely wrong" - That sounds like you are using the raw data, which is always problematic. The different data outputs have to be combined through means of sensor fusion. How are you using the data from the MPU?

Comment: use this: https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-and-mpu6050-accelerometer-and-gyroscope-tutorial/ . I attached image where I just do nothing.

Comment: You want a better gyroscope? [Here's one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYsG-lXfih8). You want a MEMS gyroscope? They're all pretty much the same, and all respond in the same way. It's *your* job to deal with the data in the *right* way.

Comment: is it explains why all sketches from internet give the same bad behavior?

Comment: You should read this: https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/raqs/raq-issue-139.html and you will then understand what you ask is an impossibility.

Comment: To be honest, I really don't see why the values are that bad. Please explain more about how they are wrong. They seems to mainly change behind the decimal point. The typical flight controller in a quadcopter also uses a similar MPU, though it also uses more different sensors for the sensor fusion, that improves the quality

Comment: @chrisl, I expect right values, like 90 degree when it is vertical and so on. May be I should use only changes of values but not values?